# How do I resolve run-time error in this code?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm getting a run-time error 3075

I have checked all the parentheses and quotes, everything seems okay but still not running.

'Now Check the database to see if there are existing records for the Month and year in question

```
txtSQL = "SELECT Count([Rec_ID]) AS CountID FROM [dbo_NBD_EMEA_NBD_Source_Download] Where [Ledger_Year] = " & CurYear & " AND [Ledger_Month] = " & CurMonth & " AND ([Region_Cd] = 'EMEA' OR [Region_Cd] = 'APAC' OR [Region_Cd] = 'INDA');"
Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set Rs = dbs.OpenRecordset(txtSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)
NumRecs = Rs("CountID")
Rs.Close
If NumRecs > 0 Then
    Prompt1 = "WARNING... There are " & NumRecs & " Records already in the database for Year " & CurYear & " Month " & CurMonth & Chr(10) & " Do you want to ERASE the existing records and REPLACE them with the NEW RECORDS in your IMPORT FILE " & Chr(10) & Selected_File & "?"
    Response1 = MsgBox(Prompt1, Style2, "DELETE EXISTING RECORDS IN DATABASE?")
    If Response1 = vbOK Then 'Continue with Delete of existing Records and Import of new
        Prompt2 = "Confirm... Existing Records will be deleted and replaced with your new file"
        Response2 = MsgBox(Prompt2, Style2, "Confirm Deletions")
            If Response2 = vbOK Then
            'Run Stored Procedure to delete the records
                Me.ProcessStatus.Caption = "Deleting existing records"
                Set db = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase("", False, False, Connect_String)
                db.Execute "XPROC1_NBD_EMEA_Source_Download_Delete " & CurYear & " , " & CurMonth, dbSQLPassThrough
                Set db = Nothing
            Else
                If Response2 = vbCancel Then 'If no confirmation of delete then cancel
                    Me.ProcessStatus.Caption = "Import Canceled"
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End If
    Else
        If Response1 = vbCancel Then ' Cancel import
            Me.ProcessStatus.Caption = "Import Canceled"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

This line does not look to be valid SQL:

```
db.Execute "XPROC1_NBD_EMEA_Source_Download_Delete " & CurYear & " , " & CurMonth, dbSQLPassThrough
```

The [`Execute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/database-execute-method-dao) method will run an action query or execute a supplied SQL statement, it does not evaluate VBA code within another database.

Comment: It's VB code used inside MS Access. What's wrong with it? I'm new to Access/SQL.

Comment: That's not how the `Execute` method works - I've updated my answer.

Comment: How do I resolve it? It's throwing up syntax error.

Run-time error '3075'
Syntax error (comma) in query expression 

'[Ledge_Year] = 019,3,3/19/2019,3/20/2019,EMEA,Q896,HUNGARY,AR-IN,ARIN-1000,S3WWERR000,